# Configurable Values In WSO2 ESB similar to .properties file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to know if there is a way to maintain certain custom configuration values in a .properties file (in Java) and load the properties at ESB startup and use the custom property values within a mediation flow? any ideas on this would be really helpful.

Comment: 1. Which version of ESB is used? 2. Should the values be used during startup or only for mediation flow?

Comment: Hi Murali, I'm using ESB 5.0.0 and values should be loaded once and used at mediation flow. It should not be read from file per request response cycle.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:
https://dzone.com/articles/retrieve-values-xml-config  (page dated ~2013)

It shows how you can have a file in the WSO2 registry and read it in your proxy. 
(the file stored in the registry can contain your properties)

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the suggestion to save the properties in an XML file which you then upload to your registry, independent of the code.
That way, the properties can be updated or deleted without having to touch the code.
If you are constrained to use Java .properties files, then it might be advisable to create a JAR that is deployed as a library, which you then call from your ESB sequence.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case, we had a custom configuration values / parameters or constants into a `global_parameter.xml` file and have it managed in a governance registry (decide based on your stack).

For example, the `global_parameter.xml` can be like the following.

```
    <custom>
        <Version>2.3</Version>
        <Type>FOR</Type>
    </custom>
```

We can load the parameters through a sequence and then use the parameters by reusing the sequence file.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="loadProperties_seq">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="localProperties" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/common/utils/properties/global_parameter.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
</sequence>
```

Refer the properties..

```
<property name="url_reg" expression="//custom/Version"/>        
<property name="user_reg" expression="//constants/Type"/>
```